# How to drop all strings in a column using a wildcard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some data that changes regularly but the column headers need to be consistent (so I cant drop the headers) but I need to clear our the strings in a given column.

This is what I have now but this only seems to work for where I know what the string is called and one at a time?

```
    df1= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Test.csv')
df2 = df1.drop(df1[~(df1['column'] != 'String1')].index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pd.drop` function which removes rows having a specific index from a dataframe.

```py
for i in df.index:
    if type(df.loc[i, 'Aborted Reason']) ==  str:
        df.drop(i, inplace = True)
```

`df.drop` will remove the index having a string in the relevant column from the dataframe.

Comment: So all i need to do is replace 'Col1' With my column where i want to drop strings?

Comment: Trying that an no strings are being dropped for me? Am i doing something wrong


 
index = [df.index[df['Aborted Reason'] == i].tolist()[0] for i in df['Aborted Reason'] if type(i) == str]
    df.drop(index)

Comment: My apologies, I have edited my answer by adding the parameter ```inplace``` to the ```pd.drop``` function. The ```inplace``` parameter will replace your existing dataframe with the new modified dataframe.

Comment: Even with the inpace=True in the pd.drop function, when im still not dropping the strings in my column?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data? Thanks

Comment: So this is a sample of my data. And I'm trying to drop any strings in the Aborted Reason colloum (G)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KAv3kYpssTALaZ2bO8v5-Zs9LxbAL7ov8pyOpciG6n0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can have a look, this should work this time